# Pull external JSON URL labels and values to new Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, getjson

In my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/UGYzW/319/ data is from local source at the moment and is simply called 'data'. How would I pull back data from external values?  Please use either http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two and pull back the value 'mralexgray' from the first login item. Do we need to push out the items to a new array or not?

Finally is it better to use JSONP, JSON or .AJAX?

```
  var data =[
        {'label':'Core','value':1},
        {'label':' Selectors','value':2},
        {'label':'Events' ,'value':3}]; 

var nameArray = data.map(function(item){
    return {value: item.value, label: item.label};
});


$("#meta-area").autocomplete({
        source:nameArray,
        select: function(e, ui) {
            e.preventDefault() // <--- Prevent the value from being inserted.
            $("#meta_search_ids").val(ui.item.label);

            $(this).val(ui.item.value);
        }
    });
    //alert("this loaded");
```

Comment: Just a side note, JSONP/JSON and AJAX are completely different things...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you created your `data` variable as an `Array`, after your ajax response push all the variables to an array. Later on same script will work with the `map` function

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/UGYzW/382/) here

```
 $.ajax({
    url:'https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/repos',  
    success:function(data) {
    var dataArray = [];
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
       dataArray.push(data[i]);
       console.log(data[i]);
    }
    var nameArray =  dataArray.map(function(item){
        return {value: item.owner, label: item.name};
    });

    $("#meta-area").autocomplete({
      source:nameArray,
      select: function(e, ui) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $("#meta_search_ids").val(ui.item.label);
          $(this).val(ui.item.value);
       }
     }); 
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks. Have you an example Ozgur?

Comment: Is getvalue.php raw JSON? I need it to work with raw JSON please. Or please show us the contents of getvalue.php. I am unsure if this will work or not.

Comment: Remember this function should work independently of any PHP, Controllers or MVC or any other back-end language. It should work as is all client side. Please see this example: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp

Comment: See this http://jsfiddle.net/UGYzW/375/ isn't working yet but should be similar to this.

Comment: i've check your fiddle page and updated it, i think thats what you want

Comment: One more query, let's say two repos shared the same id. How would we pull out the names based off this same id? E.g. data myJ =  [{
    "id": 58656723, "name": "john-Serial-Protocol"},                              "id": 58656723, "name": "jane-Serial-Protocol"},"id": 92356323,
    "name": "tome-Serial-Protocol"},] how can we show only john and jane's because they share same id.